# Spring @Autowired detection

Tags: java, spring, autowired

If I have a class which uses a spring bean, (will be wired via `@Autowired`).
I noticed that not only the class that will be injected needs the `@Component` but also the class the uses it (inject it). Why is it like that? Should not spring inject wherever `@Autowired` is? Without having to use `@Component` for the injector class?

Comment: Spring will only inject dependencies into other Spring managed beans. One way to make beans managed by Spring is to add `@Component`. Spring will not magically autowire instances into any class it doesn't know. Also even if you have `@Component` and do `new MyObject()` spring will not inject dependencies because it isn't a spring managed dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring processes and manages only those classes which are marked by one of stereotype annotations `@Component`, `@Controller`, `@Repository`, `@Service`.

It does not scan all of your classes (that would make the startup very slow).

If the class is not managed by Spring it does not process any of the annotation inside that particular class.

Answer (score 0):

In `Spring`, one works with `beans`. A `bean` is a java object that is managed by a `spring context`. When encountering a `bean` containing an `@Inject`, `Spring` will seach its `context` for a `bean` of the type of the variable to be injected. If no such `bean` is defined, `Spring` will have nothing to inject. Also, if the class with the `@Inject` doesn't have a `bean`, then `Spring` won't know about it, and thus cannot inject anything into it.

To get `Spring` to create a `bean` of a class, several methods are available. Through annotations, the class has to be annotated with `@Component`, or the more specialized annotations `@Service`, `@Repository` and `@Controller`. Only then will `Spring` create a `bean` for the class that can be `@Inject`ed into other `beans`.